# TowerPro SG90 servo motor: adding analog feedback

Tags: arduino, analog, servo

**TL;DR:** Where exactly did the [Hexy guys connect the feedback cable](http://arcbotics.com/products/metalgearservo/)?

I would like to:

1. Remove the 180° limitation of those servos. Did that with an [instructables tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-TowerPro-Micro-Servo-Spin-360/?ALLSTEPS) (TL;DR: remove piece of plastic from gears and potentiometer to let it spin 360º).
2. Read the actual position via some analog cue present in the servo board.

What I've tried is connecting a couple of pins from the servo's [AA51880](http://www.cambot.net/DATA/DATABOOK/AA51880(SERVO%20CPU).pdf) to analog pins A0 and A1 of an arduino:

[image: AA51880 chip view]

Here's the result when plotting pins `Rdb` and `Pot` from [AA51880](http://www.cambot.net/DATA/DATABOOK/AA51880(SERVO%20CPU).pdf):

[image: nominal state plot]

All screenshots are just with the default servo initialization as coded in [johnny-five.io](http://johnny-five.io) with Arduino's Firmata:

```
  var servo = new five.Servo({
    pin: 9,
    startAt: 90
  });
```

No sweeps nor movements are coded to drive this servo.

Then, when I perturb the servo manually, the servo spins a few times on its own (presumably the [AA51880](http://www.cambot.net/DATA/DATABOOK/AA51880(SERVO%20CPU).pdf) correcting position) and the readings look like this:

[image]

And this in a different timepoint and position:

[image]

I also get spurious, uncontrolled spins of the motor when not actuating it at all. Is it possible I'm injecting noise to the board? Should I add a pullup resistor somewhere in my setup?

[image: servo]
[image: servo_board_back]
[image: servo_board_front]

The question is, given the above readings, is there are way to reliably read the voltage/position of those cheap servos using the arduino ADCs while removing the 180° limitation?

Comment: You are asking us to read three links, one of which is a six-page Instructables tutorial. That's a big ask.

Comment: Gotcha, TL;DR on the instructables: Remove a piece of plastic in the gears and another piece of plastic/metal in the servo potentiometer to let it spin freely. Works? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We attach the analog feedback wire directly to the middle pin on the potentiometer. This does mean that you need to watch out for the impedance of the reading input - we usually use an [opamp voltage-follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier#Op-amp_implementation) to mitigate this.

Comment: Thanks a lot ArcBotics, I ended up adding a simple [SMD NPN J3Y](http://www.hz-dz.net/UploadFiles/2009527101530473.pdf) and the plots look much better now... although they still need some signal smoothing with some caps and software, but I can take it from there. Thanks again ArcBotics! ;)